# Accessing UILabel created on run time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created `UILabel (lblCount)` and `UIButton (btnAdd)` on a `UIButton (Add Item Button)`'s action method. The new `UILabel` and `UIButton` is added to `scrollview`. The `UILabel (lblCount)` shows count of `UIButton (btnAdd)` tapped. Here, `addBtnClickCount` is an integer which counts the number of click.

```
    UILabel * lblCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 50, 100*addBtnClickCount, 25, 25)];
    lblCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
    lblCount.tag = addBtnClickCount;
    lblCount.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblCount.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:lblCount];

    addBtnClickCount = addBtnClickCount+1;
```

There will be multiple `label (lblCount)` and `button (btnAdd)` when user taps Add Item Button. I want to access particular `label` for particular `add button` and `display the count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already set tag on your label. Create a mutable array labelArray and add label to it. To access the particular label do following code on add button's action.

```
       -(void)addItem:(UIButton*)button{
          UILabel* lblShowCount = [_labelArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
          lblShowCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [lblShowCount.text integerValue]+1];

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here i understand that @Hem Poudyal, know's that with help of `viewWithTag`.he will get output. but don't know how to achieved that. so i am describing over here.

Step 1: Here i am adding `UILabel` and `UIButton` to `self.view`  instead of `UIScrollView`. i hope you can convert it as `UIScrollView`. here i applied some relation between `UILabel tag` and `UIButton tag`. that you can see in below code.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        UILabel * lblCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 50, (i*50)+((i+1)*5), 100, 50)];
        lblCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0];
        lblCount.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",i,i] integerValue];
        lblCount.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        lblCount.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.view addSubview:lblCount];

        UIButton* btnTemp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnTemp.tag = i;
        btnTemp.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [btnTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTempClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnTemp.frame = CGRectMake( 150, (i*50)+((i+1)*5), 100, 50);
        [btnTemp setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button : %d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:btnTemp];
    }
```

Step 2: In UIButton selector method, Do the following things.

```
-(IBAction)btnTempClick:(id)sender{
    UIButton* btnInner = sender;

    NSInteger lblTagbaseOnButtonTag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%ld",btnInner.tag,btnInner.tag] integerValue];
    UILabel* lblReceived = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:lblTagbaseOnButtonTag];
    lblReceived.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[lblReceived.text integerValue]+1];
}
```

And Output is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should have an array that you add the labels and buttons too (this could be one array containing a dictionary or custom class or multiple arrays). Now, when a button is tapped you can find where it is in the array and get the corresponding label to update.

The cheat way is to set the `tag` of the buttons and labels so you can find one from the other using `viewWithTag:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set unique `tag` value while creating the labels and buttons and by using `viewWithTag:` you can access the respective ui container.